# Inferring type of values returned by the SQLite3 shell tool

Tags: shell, sqlite

I am out of necessity using the SQLite3 shell tool to maintain a small database. I'm using `-header -ascii` flags, although this applies—as far as I can tell—to any of the output choices. I'm looking a way to avoid ambiguity over the type of any one value returned. Consider the following:

```
Create Table `things` (`number` Integer, `string` Text, `binary` Blob);
Insert Into `things` (`number`,`string`,`binary`) Values (4,'4',X'34');
Select * From `things`;
```

This returns (using [caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation)):

```
number^_string^_binary^^4^_4^_4^^
```

As is evident, there is no way to infer the type of any of the '4' characters *from the response alone* as none of them have distinguishing delimiters.

*Is there any way to coerce the inclusion of type metadata into the response?*

I'd like to avoid:

- Altering query statements to also include types as that would be obfuscatory and would be superfluous in the event I did switch interfaces;
- Prefixing TEXT and BLOB values prior to insert as this would have to be uniform for *all* TEXT and BLOB interaction (in saying that, this is still my preferred choice should it come to that).

What I'm looking for is a switch of some kind that indicates type as part of SQLite's response, e.g.:

```
number^_string^_binary^^4^_'4'^_X'4'^^
number^_string^_binary^^4^_text:4'^blob:4^^
```

Or some variation thereof. Fundamental to this is the response alone contains enough information to discern the type and value of each element of that response (much in the same way `sqlite3_column_type()` allows in the SQLite Library API).

Update: I've refined this question since the first answer by @mike-sherrill-cat-recall to clarify expectations.

Comment: Consider using the SQLite API, instead of trying to parse the output of the shell.

Comment: @colonel-thirty-two I have considered the API, indeed I've adapted wrappers for the API long ago in my language of choice that it work the way I want it. In this instance, I am in need of the shell version and genuinely find it difficult to believe that this isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite, it doesn't always make sense to echo the data type of a column. SQLite doesn't *have* column-wise data types in the traditional sense. You can use `typeof(X)` in SQL to show the "datatype of the expression X".

```
sqlite> create table test (n integer, d decimal(8, 2));
sqlite> insert into test (n, d) values (8, 3.14);

sqlite> insert into test (n, d) values ('wibble', 'wibble');
```

Inserting text into an integer column succeeds.

```
sqlite> select n, typeof(n), d, typeof(d) from test;
```

```
    n           typeof(n)   d           typeof(d) 
    ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
    8           integer     3.14        real      
    wibble      text        wibble      text
```

You can concatenate anything you like--even producing caret notation--but it's kind of clumsy.

```
sqlite> select '(' || typeof(n) || ')^_' || n as caret_n from test;
```

```
    caret_n                  
    -------------------------
    (integer)^_8             
    (text)^_wibble
```

---

[SQLite Core Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html)

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to find a way to get that without modifying the core queries (how do you do this for **\*** anyway?). My fear is that this is a (surprising) deficiency in SQLite's shell output.

Comment: @rgchris: I can't think of any SQL command-line interface that prints type data in the output. I never use `select * from...` in production.

Comment: @mike-sherrill-cat-recall The SQLite library interface includes basic type information in its response. Others do per-column. Given the example in my question, it would seem a pertinent and indeed fundamental part of any response.

Comment: @rgchris: I don't understand what "Others do per-column." means here.

Comment: @mike-sherrill-cat-recall For example, the MySQL TCP protocol precedes its data response with column metadata, including types. Most data APIs return typed values in JSON form—which for all its deficiencies provides ample distinction between strings and integers.

Comment: @rgchris: I see. But the MySQL command-line interface *doesn't* return data types in *its* output. If you can't use the library interface in your particular situation, it just muddies the waters to keep referring to it.

Comment: Perhaps it does muddy the waters, but that's what I need. To me Library and Shell are just two ways of communicating—sure the processes are different, but I don't see why the outcomes should be. I absolutely cannot see the point in returning half-baked delimited results, either do or don't—if the output isn't intended for parsing, why is there even an `-ascii` mode? Those delimiters don't print in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The shell always converts printed values to strings. (That's what "print" means.)

If you don't want to add separate output columns for the types, you could use the [quote function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#quote) to output all values according to SQL syntax rules:

```
sqlite> with v(x) as (values (null), (1), (2.3), ('hello'), (x'00')) select quote(x) from v;
NULL
1
2.3
'hello'
X'00'
```

Comment: 'The shell always...'—you'll have heard of [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization), it's amazing how much information can be conveyed in strings. How do you use **quote()** in a general sense, say applied to the result of a query?

Comment: It's a function, just like length() or typeof().

Comment: And thus would require altering the SQL statement. Would be close if I could say **With v(x) As (Select * From `things`) Select Quote(x) From v;** or **With v(x) As (...my query here...) Select Quote(x) From v;** Alas it doesn't seem to work that way.

Comment: The [CTE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) is just for getting values without a real table; just write `SELECT quote(x) FROM ...`.